# Events Plugin that works with existing categories?

Tags: plugins, categories, events

I have a series of categories on my website that are fixed, i.e. The client has specifically asked that I leave them.

Now however, they would like me to add an events plugin so they are able to add events.

Every plugin I've found insists that you create your own event specific categories, thus losing the permalinks structure and the menu structure that is already in place.

If I wanted to add an event to Category 1 because it's subject matter is related to Category 1, then I can't.

Does anyone know of a way to either modify an existing events plugin to this purpose, or of a plugin that already implements it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My plugin ([amr-events](http://icalevents.com)) will work with existing categories (and you can choose  standard posts or custom post types)  There is also a way to convert any existing posts into 'event' posts in case there is alot of content already built into a post for an event.

It is a paid plugin (the free version at [test](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/amr-ical-events-list/)) works with ics files, They share the same recurring and listing engine for event data.  See the rating at wp.

You can test out amr-events out for free at [test.icalvents.com](http://test.icalevents.com)